# Watch setting value of properties

Tags: c#

is there a possibility to watch value changes of properties without calling PropertyChanged (System.ComponentModel) for every property in setter?

I tried watching my properties with Timer, but this has an unnecessary negative effect on Performance and is too slow (15ms for every run).

Comment: You could use some IL weaving like [Fody.PropertyChanged](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged) to automatically create the property change implementation.

Comment: Why you need this? Usually a property has a getter and a setter, so you know exactly when its value changes. As long as no-one changes the value it should stay the same, shouldn´t it? In all the other cases use an event - as PropertyChanged, that´s what it´s supposed to do.

Comment: From what I understand the reason you don't want to use  PropertyChanged is beacuse you don't want to add it to all your properties? You want to single point to watch all your properties?

Comment: This is exactly what I want, @ShaiAharoni. For explanation: We have our own framework for many applications and other developer in company uses this framework. It's hard to teach them using INotifyPropertyChanged everytime and then they wonder that nothing happens because the framework only triggers to changed properties ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, what you need is automatically add `INotifyPropertyChanged` to classes. This can be achieve in a several ways.

Here is a partial list:
[Roslyn](https://github.com/neuecc/NotifyPropertyChangedGenerator), [Fody](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged), [Castle](http://www.castleproject.org/projects/dynamicproxy/), [PostSharp](https://www.postsharp.net/product), [Spring.Net](http://springframework.net/) etc.

To choose one, you need to define your requirements.
If you want dynamic proxy\ AOP or to do it with IL weaving or you want to add it with code fix inside VS.

Comment: Roslyn sounds good. Not least due to the fact that VS already implements it. AFAIK the others are all third party libraries, right? Then will be the next step to figure out how it can be realized with Roslyn ...